# Parse GSA XML List with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, google-search-appliance, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have the following XML response from a GSA server.
Basically it has

```
<GSP>
 <RES>
  <M>
  <R id=1>
  </R>
  <R id=2>
  </R>
 </RES>
</GSP>
```

How can I parse this XML with Jackson? Here is my code

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "GSP")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RespuestaGSARoot {

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "RES")
private ResultadoBusqueda res;
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "RES")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResultadoBusqueda {

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "M")
private int total;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "R")
private List<ResultadoPagina> resultados;
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "R")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResultadoPagina {

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "U")
private String url;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "T")
private String titulo;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "S")
private String descripcion;}
```

They all have the setters and getters, this is just an example. I can go till the RES, but I cant get the field "resultados" filled with the list of  R results.
This error occurs:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.tm.buscador.domain.ResultadoPagina] from String value ('http://negocios.movistar.com.ar/tienda/lineas-y-planes/comunidad-negocios-full/'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@642f9a77; line: 20, column: 99] (through reference chain: com.tm.buscador.domain.RespuestaGSARoot["RES"]->com.tm.buscador.domain.ResultadoBusqueda["R"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="R")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private List<ResultadoPagina> resultados;
```